# UITextView on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, uitextview, ios5

I was testing an iphone application which I have created that uses a UITextView and I noticed that the Text on UITextView iOS 5 is not showing, I tried to change its color, still the same,

Any one have tried it

Issam

Comment: This is under NDA, use the Apple Dev forums until the Fall, when iOS 5 will become public.

Comment: Remember that iOS 5 is still under NDA.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Perhaps its not an iOS5 issue, please show your code, if it's not under NDA.